# how to handle NullPointerException in this code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am new at java and i have this exception in my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Course.addStudents(Course.java:31)
    at Third.main(Third.java:28)
```

Course.java

```
public boolean addStudents(Student newStudent){
     for (Student student : students){
         if (student.getID()== newStudent.getID()){
             return false;
         }
     }
     if(numberOfStudents < capacity){    
         students[numberOfStudents++] = newStudent;
         return true;
     }
     return false;
     }
```

Third.java

```
c1.addStudents(s1);
```

I have tried the solve it but didnt achieve. I searched for it and I guess the problem is initializing. Is it true? if it is, I dont know how to handle with that, any idea??

Comment: Is `students` initialized? Are all its elements initialized?

Comment: What line is line 31 in Course.java?

Comment: no it isnt but i dont know how to initialize it?

Comment: line 31: for (Student student : students){

Comment: where is your 'students' list??

Comment: What is your `students` declaration?

Comment: students = new Student[capacity]; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: If you don't know how to initialize students try this : List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

Comment: You will get NullPointerException if you don't initialize your Students collection. So it should be initialized as  `Student[] students = new Student[capacity];`

Comment: @DavidBo and user2065083 : read the code. students is an array, not a List.

Comment: where should i initialize it? in Third.java?

Comment: Post the code in which you are using `course`.

Comment: @user3075117 In the place where you declared the array. Or show us Course.java code.

Answer (score 3):

As per your comment

```
  for (Student student : students){
```

students is an array and not initialized.

Since you are using arrays , that initialization would be

```
Student[] students = new Student[capacity];
```

Remmeber that when you intialize an array ,default values will be `null` untill unless you fill them. In your loop you have to check for `null` as again it causes `NullPOinterException`

```
 for (Student student : students){   
         if (student !=null && student.getID()== newStudent.getID()){
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Comment: No look the later codes `students[numberOfStudents++] = newStudent;` OP is trying to use an array I guess.

Comment: While true, he's also going to need a check for `null` inside his loop, since the elements of the array aren't initialized.

Answer (score 2):

the problem, is indeed initializing, one or more of the below is not initialized:

newStudent, students.

as Student is an object it needs an initialization before you can use it, as opposed to primitive types.